# Ckeditor breaking a tag into two

Tags: javascript, ckeditor4.x

When I am trying to copy paste below html into ckeditor it's breaking `a` tag into two

**Original Content**

```
<figure class="img-caption" style="width: 259px; margin-right: 6px;">
    <a class="wrapper" href="/in/software-defined-datacenter/index.html" target="_top" name="&amp;lpos=product : 37">
         <img src="/files/images/topics/carousel/vmw-crsl-software-defined-data-center.jpg" alt="Software-Defined Data Center" title="">
         <figcaption class="semi-transparent">
             <p>Software-Defined Data Center</p>
         </figcaption>
   </a>
</figure>
```

**Content after pasting**

```
<figure style="....">
    <a style="...">
        <img data-cke-saved-src="random.jpg" src="randowm.jpg" style="...">
    </a>
    <figcaption style="...">
        <p style="....">
            <a style="....">Software-Defined Data Center</a>
        </p>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

*I have omitted styles in pasted content for better readability.*

As you can see ckeditor is generating one extra `a` tag after pasting. Is there any way I can avoid ckeditor generating a new `a` tags.

My configuration is

```
config.pasteFilter = {
    $1: {
        elements:CKEDITOR.dtd,
        styles: true
    },
    'img': {
        attributes: '!src',
        styles: true
    }
};
```

I don't have any configuration in `config.allowedContent`